# Android Build tools not installed on Centos7

Tags: android, linux, centos, android-build

I am trying to setup Android Build tools installed on my CentOS 7 machine as part of Continuous Integration for a Mobile project.

We have a corporate proxy and
1) I have set proxy variables in /etc/environment
2) I have set up proxy information in gradle.properties( in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties (for building my mobile project)

I followed these instructions to install Android SDK

```
 #Download and Install Android SDK. 
 mkdir -p /opt/sdk-tools-linux-3859397
 cd /opt/sdk-tools-linux-3859397
 sudo wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
 sudo unzip sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
 cd /opt
 sudo chown -R root:root sdk-tools-linux-3859397
 sudo ln -s sdk-tools-linux-3859397 android-sdk

 sudo vim /etc/profile.d/android-sdk-env.sh

 # Set Android SDK Environment Value.
 export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"
 export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"

 sudo source /etc/profile.d/android-sdk-env.sh


 #Update Android SDK
 /opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools" "build-tools;26.0.0"
```

The last step which is Updation of build tools gets stuck and after some time I get this error

```
Info: Parsing /opt/sdk-tools-linux-3859397/tools/package.xml
Info: Parsing /opt/sdk-tools-linux-3859397/tools/package.xml
Info: IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
Info: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
Info: IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Info: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
Info: IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Info: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
```

Any idea on how to get the build tools in my build server.
I went through of questions and solutions but many of them were suggesting to use Android Studio UI and I am looking to install through command line.

I also tried below command as per [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

```
/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.1" --proxy_host="uname:password@proxyhost" --proxy_port=8080
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like a network problem

Comment: If it was network problem, then the download of sdk package itself would have failed. Without setting the proxy, download won't happen as well. I have checked that.

Comment: Why `sudo chown -R root:root ...`? You took away access for everyone. Usually `/opt`'s permissions are fine for this sort of thing. In fact, I drop the NDK there and have never needed to change permissions.

Comment: But even as a root I am unable to update.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution.
I think these 'proxy' servers are there to complicate lives.
One of my colleague suggested to use cntlm proxy and it works fine.
Followed [CNTLM Proxy Instructions](https://wingloon.com/2014/04/11/how-to-install-and-configure-cntlm-to-access-isa-server-on-centos-6-5/)
Then I executed the command :

```
/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --no_https --proxy=http --proxy_host=127.0.0.1 --proxy_port=3128 "build-tools;26.0.1"
```

Note this time I have replaced proxy host and proxy port with the cntlm config.

It works fine.
However I am still unsure even after setting system proxy why do we need a cntlm proxy. It is like proxy on top of another proxy.

Comment: That's because Microsoft uses another security protocol (NTLM) than everybody else.